# Documize Knowledge Base: How to remove a login button from Knowledge base page?

Tags: knowledge-management

I am utilizing Documize for knowledge management. However, I've encountered an issue where the login button appears on my published knowledge base page. Can someone guide me on how to remove the login button from my published Documize knowledge management page?

We have created a docker image for Documize in Azure to use Documize as knowledge base. After creating a content in Documize. I have published my knowledge base but the login button appears on the published page. How remove/hide login button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQHAp.png)